# Ошибка при интеграции кнопки PlusOneButton google api

Tags: android, google-play, google-api, google-play-services, google-plus

У меня есть вот такой ListView

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_refresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="@color/colorGrey"
            android:dividerHeight="5dp"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

И есть кастомный item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_image_black_24dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name" />


    <com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton xmlns:plus="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.android.gms.plus"
        android:id="@+id/plus_one_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        plus:annotation="inline"
        plus:size="standard" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Вывожу список предложений. Я хочу чтоб у каждого предложения была кнопка своя +1 но у меня не чего не выводи когда я добавляю кнопку, без кнопки все ок!

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:10.0.0'
}
```

В предпросмотре item.xml выдает вот это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я гуглил эту проблему и нашёл коммент в котором писали что эта проблема возникает если юзать библиотеку com.google.android.gms:play-services выше 7 версии, ну я не думаю что google выкидывал в продакшен не рабочую версию и как бы уже вышла 10-я, я подозреваю они изменили api кнопки или что-то подобное, я интегрировал кнопку с помощью вот этой документацией от google:
https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/recommend
может это старая документация и есть новая?

Comment: Не понятно в какой момент возникает эта ошибка. Добавьте больше подроностей в вопрос

Comment: Вот изображение ошибки

Comment: Т.е. проблема у вас только в предпросмотрорщике? Если да - просто не пользуйтесь им. Он очень плохо работатет. На девайсе/эмуляторе проблем у вас не будет

Comment: Не, у меня не только в предпросмотре, у меня не выводит список с этой кнопкой, без все норм!

Comment: В приведённой вами в вопросе информации нет ничего про список. На скрине - ошибка превью. Пока вы не предоставите больше информации помочь вам никак нельзя.